# SQL bullk inserts if records do not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert

As part of my build I am changing some .sql files. As it is now, the queries delete particular records from the table and re-add them during the install. What we'd like to have is a check, to see if certain records exist. If they are, do nothing, but if they aren't perform ~30 inserts.

Again these are .sql files and I can't seem to get the syntax right. I think it should be

`IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE x = bar) <= 0
THEN 
BEGIN
Insert statements... 
END
END IF;`

But this doesn't seem to be working for me. I have also taken a look at IF NOT EXISTS but that as well has not been working. The MERGE command I dont believe is relevant here because I am not pulling from a separate table, just hard-coded insert statements. I am using Oracle SQL developer, am I missing something?

*SOLVED* 
This worked for me:

```
insert into table (col1, col2) 
select 'val1','val2'
from dual
where not exists(select * 
                 from table
                 where (col1 ="val1" and col2='val2'));
```

Comment: In what way does it "not seem to be working" for you. Surely you understand this is an airy fairy statement. I you can't define how this is not functioning there's no way you can fix it.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I just didn't have oracle in front of me at the moment. Sql developer is giving an error stating incorrect syntax. So I figured I was in the right ballpark.

Comment: I got over my grumpines and posted an answer... I don't have Oracle on front of me either :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I don't have oracle handy)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (PK, COl2, Col3)
SELECT 1, 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PK = 1);
```

The select only returns records of the record doesn't exist (matching on the `PK` column)

You can do one of those per record or you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (PK, COl2, Col3)
SELECT 1, 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PK = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PK = 2);
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PK = 3);
```

This is probably OK for half a dozen records (it can be generated from Excel formulas).

Comment: I see your point here but it may be impractical for ~ 30 inserts no?

Comment: I also have a composite key but that should not matter

Comment: No more impractical than the other answer. It can easily be generated from excel.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use SQL if an IF statement like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE x = bar) <= 0
```

So what you need to do is execute the count then test it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
into v_count
FROM foo WHERE x = bar;

if v_count <= 0
THEN 
BEGIN
Insert statements... 
END;
END IF;
```

Comment: Yes see this is something I was thinking. But is this considered PL/SQL? I am getting a compilation error on the last END. Is it not possible to perform
IF NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM foo where primary_key = 1)
THEN
insert statements...
END IF;
?

Comment: *is this considered PL//SQL?* Well what I wrote is, but I was making an assumption about what was represented by "insert statements..." If this doesn't work for you you'll need to post more details. But certainly that IF statement you posted is **not** valid PL/SQL.

Comment: Sure. I guess while there are lots of methods that work in triggers with with PL/SQL I'm not sure if this will run in the .sql file that runs when my app installs. By inster statements i mean around 30 rows. Like 
IF (condition)
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES ('bar', 'foo')
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
END IF;

Comment: Trying your method seems right to me but I am getting..

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted

Comment: That's a compilation: I cannot see the script you're actually running so I cannot tell you what's wrong. Although I should point out that my pseudo- code replicated the typo in your pseudo-code and omitted the semi-colon from the END statement. That could be it.

Comment: i've posted an edit. It seems to be closer now but it seems like there's a syntax issue still. I mean this functionality has to exist, this can't be the reason why the team before chose to delete the table and re-insert it on every install.